# Call javascript or set element focus from CHtmlView

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I have a CHtmlView instance that will always load a known page. There is an edit box element on the page, and I would like to be able to set the keyboard focus to the element programmatically in response to a serial event. Unfortunately I'm stuck using Visual Studio 6 and am finding the documentation difficult to wade through.

I can get a IHTMLDocument2 interface to the view, but not IHTMLDocument3. What I am looking for is some guidance on how to either call javascript from the CHtmlView side, or set the focus in the window to a specific element.

If anyone knows of any examples they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [nice article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/browsercontrol/article.php/c6175/Creating-an-Internet-Explorer-Helper-Class.htm) should be your starting point. has an example how to fill a form